# How to change font size for 'let' keyword in Netbeans?

Tags: javascript, netbeans

The fact that the let keyword is not recognized and not highlighted as a var in JSX in Netbeans is a bug but for some reason it is also one size font smaller.

How do I change that? I went through all Editor and Font&Color settings and couldn't find where I could fix it.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I remember I increased font size for most categories but this one stayed the same small size, I didn't bother increasing it, I think. Now I need to increase it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are aware of some custom tweaks you made directly in netbeans config files. The `let` is keyword, which isn't for some reason recognized. Consider reinstalling netbeans, because as far as I know, It's not possible to change font&color for a single keyword, It's always for groups like keywords, comments, operators, and so on. Export your settings first.

Comment: let is not recognized and it's a known bug. That's what I'm trying to find i.e. a category/group to which let belongs. And it's not exactly a useful advice because if I export the settings then it will just be replicated in the new installation.

Comment: I just test it in NB 8.2 on win and my `let` is a keyword, and properly colored. Changing keyword font&color change `let` as well as other keywords.

Comment: You are right, it's working. Maybe I should've restarted Netbeans after going through all my settings.